# WKWebView not displaying website (Swift 4, iOS 11, Xcode 9.3)

Tags: ios, swift, web, https, wkwebview

For some reason, the WKWebView in my app won't display any websites like "https://www.google.com.au". 
I have tried changing the "Allow Arbitrary Loads" to "YES" in info.plist but that didn't resolve the issue.

PLEASE HELP!!!!!
Thanks

My Code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        displayWebPage()
    }

    private func displayWebPage() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com.au")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

Screenshot of StoryBoard:
[image: StoryBoard]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved ? If yes, please update it with an answer. I have a similar issue. Thanks!

Comment: No I didn't get it resolved. I had to use code instead of the storyboard. Thanks

Comment: In my case that was resolved by NSAppTransportSecurity setting in info.plist.

Comment: Have you checked whether any antivirus enabled n ur system ? I got a similar issue and resolved by turning off my avg antivirus webshield.

Comment: @Vineeth Yes, that was the problem. Apologies everyone for not updating this post. If the same issue occurs and you've tried everything, like Vineeth said, it's probably because there is some anti-virus webshield active.

Answer (score 3):

Connect the WKNavigationDelegate, this will fix the webpage not loading try the below code. Any errors thrown while loading the webpage will be printed in the webViewDidFail delegate.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        displayWebPage()
    }

    private func displayWebPage() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com.au")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(request)
    }
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code but the screen is still blank (white screen) and no error messages are popping up

Comment: Try call `displayWebPage:` after 'ViewWillAppear:Animated' method.

Comment: Are you sure it did work for me though, and please verify the outlets are connected.

Comment: calling the function after ViewWillAppear doesn't work and yes, my outlets are connected. Is there a possibility that it's not my code that's wrong, but maybe the Xcode Settings or the Simulator settings?

Answer (score 1):

set webView delegates.

```
    webView.UIDelegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

and also try by adding your domain in exception domain list

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>google.com.au</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score -1):

Connect your controller to `WKUIDelegate`, add `loadView()` method in your View Controller and initialize your web view using `WKWebViewConfiguration`.

```js
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let myConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: myConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        displayWebPage()
    }

    private func displayWebPage() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com.au")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

Source: [WK Web View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview)